# How to run repeatedly a proc in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have written a proc in tcl which takes one argument (a positive integer) und displays a text. Lets call it **permu** (for permutation). I would like to execute this proc permanently, so

```
puts [permu 3]
```

and with the same argument (here 3), lets say every 2 or 3 seconds or so, without removing the previous outcome of the code. How can I do this?

The second question: Same question as above but I would like to clear the screen when the new outcome of permu is displayed.

Third question: In case that I decide to stop a running code (I work with Linux), for example the one above, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: clear the screen: `exec clear`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do the repeated output:

```
proc repeat_permu {arg delay} {
   puts [permu $arg]
   after $delay [list repeat_permu $arg $delay]
}

# Note that the delay is in milliseconds
repeat_permu 3 3000

# Now start the event loop
vwait forever
```

To clear the screen you need to send the appropriate escape sequence before each new output. Most terminal emulators will accept the vt100 code, so you would do `puts "\x1b[2J"`.

Normally you could just stop your program running by typing control-c, or do you want some means of doing this programmatically?

Update: A simpler way to do the repetition if you don't need to process any other events in parallel is just: `while 1 {puts [permu 3]; after 3000}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your code is working but it is not running automatically. The code should be executed automatically every 3 seconds after its first call. I do not want to call it myself (except the first time). So, after its first call, the procedure repeat_permu must be able to call itself (every 3 seconds). Sorry, my explanation was not clear at this point.

Comment: Needs a `vwait forever` after the initial function call for the `after` to work.

Comment: @Shawn is right, I forgot that you need to enter the event loop.

Comment: Actually if you don't have any other events needing to be processed in parallel you could just do `while 1 {puts [permu 3]; after 3000}`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! As Shawn suggested, I added "vwait forever" into the last line of Colin's proc repeat_permu, that is, after the command "after $delay [list repeat_permu $arg $delay]". This is correct, isn't it? With this improvement, the code is definitely working fine anyway.

Comment: No `vwait forever` should be added right at the end of the code, after the call to the proc, not inside its definition.  Calling vwait inside the proc will work for a while, but since it never returns it will eventually cause a literal *stack overflow*.

Comment: You might want to add this to the code snippet of the answer, so that the example is complete?